# Инициализация tinymce по содержимому существующего блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Прикручиваю редактор на фронтенд и возникла проблема, как инициализировать `tinymce`.

Мой код:

```
<head>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a class=pageedit>Редактировать</a>
<div id="textwidget" class="textwidget">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati esse enim facilis quam magnam nihil excepturi ipsa, maxime ducimus sapiente, repudiandae facere mollitia, velit quia dolore doloribus molestiae odit fuga?
</div>
</body>

 /*JQUERY*/
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('a.pageedit').on('click', function() {

          $('#textwidget').wrap('<form class="tinymce"><textarea class="tiny" name="page"></textarea></form>');

          $(this).unbind('click');
          setTimeout(function() {
             Tinit();
          },100);
      });

  });

function Tinit() {
      tinymce.init({ 
        selector:'textarea.tiny',
        height: 600,
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
      });

      $('form.tinymce').submit(function() {
         return false;
      });

      $('form.tinymce').on('submit', function() {
        var page = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'publish.php',
          data: page,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            document.location.href = '';
          },
          error: function() {
            alert('error');
          }
        });
      });

}
```

В итоге редактор загружается, но внутри пусто. Как можно решить?

Воспроизводится здесь: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZEEwG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете следующий код:

```
$('#textwidget').wrap('<form class="tinymce"><textarea class="tiny" name="page"></textarea></form>');
```

В итоге получается, что ваш div оказывается внутри textarea. Это некорректно с точки зрения разметки. Отсюда пустой редактор.

Используйте метод [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/), он обернет текст внутри div в ваши теги.
Пример:

```
$('#textwidget').wrapInner('<form class="tinymce"><textarea class="tiny" name="page"></textarea></form>');
```

Он подходит для **вашего** случая, когда внутри div только текст.

У меня не получилось вставить код в сниппет из-за `same-origin`, поэтому вот ссылка на [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZppow).

---

В других случаях, когда в блоке не только текст, надо действовать иначе.

Например, если нужно только содержимое из известного блока:

- сохранить содержимое из div в переменную
- спрятать оригинальный блок
- с помощью [`.insetAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) добавить форму с textarea после оригинального div
- присвоить значение textarea из сохраненной ранее переменной
- инициализировать tinymce

Или если нужно содержимое из известного блока, включая код самого блока:

- обернуть искомый блок в любой подходящий по семантике элемент-обертку
- обратиться к обертке с помощью `.parent()` и с помощью `.html()` получить содержимое в переменную. В этом содержимом будет и код искомого блока.
- с помощью [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) примененного к искомому блоку удалить обертку
- спрятать оригинальный блок
- с помощью [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) добавить форму с textarea после оригинального div
- присвоить значение textarea из сохраненной ранее переменной
- инициализировать tinymce

Вот пример реализации к последнему варианту: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZppow)

Comment: ок, более менее понятно, но как корректно присвоить значение textarea,    в случае когда туда нужно поместить html разметку?

Comment: просто если не пользоваться wrap(), а сразу сделать такую разметку с формой и т.п., то все отлично работает и код страницы улетает на сервер без проблем. А вот с изменением DOM так не прокатило

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer я добавил пример

Comment: Спасибо, проверить в бою это решение к сожалению пока не могу. Но на вскидку более лаконичное решение получил здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920340/problems-with-initialize-tinymce. Вам огромный плюс))

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, главное, чтобы вы поняли, почему контент был пустой. Не вставляйте элементы внутрь textarea. Способ передачи контента в редактор не так важен, но, на мой взгляд, лучше использовать API. Плюсанул тот ответ.